# When I Click the Run Button, Apps Stops running with an error- Android App

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-activity

I am programming a mortgage calculator app. I thought I have finished the app and it should work now. However every time I click the button "Calculate Monthly Payment", the app stops and exit immediately with the error message **"Unfortunately, your app has stopped"**.

Here is my  code fragment for the ***MainActivity.java***:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
{
    Button button;
    EditText borrowedAmt;
    SeekBar interestRate;
    RadioGroup loanTerm;
    RadioButton termChosen;
    CheckBox taxAndInsur; 
    TextView monthlyPay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        borrowedAmt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        loanTerm = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        monthlyPay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        taxAndInsur = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        interestRate = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        // SeekBar
        interestRate.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
        {
            int progressChanged = 0;

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
            {
                progressChanged = progress;
            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Rate chosen = " + progressChanged, 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        //Button

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                double borrowedAmtValue = 0.0;
                double rateValue = 0.0;
                int noOfLoanMonth = 0;
                double taxAndInsurValue = 0.0;
                double monthlyPayValue = 0.0;

                // Borrowed amount processing
                borrowedAmtValue = Double.parseDouble(borrowedAmt.getText().toString());

                // Interest Rate processing
                rateValue = interestRate.getProgress() / 1200;

                // Loan Term processing
                int[] termGroup = {180, 240, 360};
                int selectedTerm = loanTerm.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                noOfLoanMonth = termGroup[selectedTerm];

                // Tax and Insurance Included processing
                if (taxAndInsur.isChecked()) 
                    taxAndInsurValue = borrowedAmtValue * 0.001;
                else 
                    taxAndInsurValue = 0.0;

                //making the keyboard disappear after clicking the button
                InputMethodManager objInputMM = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
                            Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                objInputMM.hideSoftInputFromWindow(termChosen.getWindowToken(), 0);

                //Calculating total interest value 
                monthlyPayValue = borrowedAmtValue * (rateValue / (1 - Math.pow(1 + rateValue, - noOfLoanMonth)));

                // setting the result into the textview's text property to display to the user
                monthlyPay.setText(Double.toString(monthlyPayValue));
                //txtVwCalculatedInterest.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCDEF"));

                // resetting text boxes
                //loanAmt.setText("");
                //loanTenure.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/enter_borrowed_amt"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/choose_int_rate"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:progress="10"
        android:max="20"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/choose_term"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="clip_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/yr15" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/yr20" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/yr30" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/check_tni" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/calculate" 
        android:onClick="setOnClickListener"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/monthly_pay"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When I run the app on emulator, I realize when I click the button, that the logcat window brings up tons of red lines, so I think there is something wrong here but I don't know how to detect it. Please help me. Thanks much!

My catlog: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ab0m7y05dzzsc9u/Untitled.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Post your logcat then....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: @SamHo Nothing found at your link.....plz check it..

Comment: @Sam Ho please post the error content in your question not link as I am not member or any other user member of your dropbox site.

Comment: i cant, my reputation is not enough to post a photo @Pratik

Comment: @MD I fixed the link to public.

Comment: @SamHo your logcat clearly said your issue is not about Button click....but it's about some ArrayIndeaOutofBound ....

Comment: It is logcat not catlog

Answer (score 1):

You defined  `android:onClick="setOnClickListener"` at your `Button` in your `activity_main` layout so you need to implement `setOnClickListener` a method in your `Activity` just like:

```
public void setOnClickListener(View v) {

///do your job

}
```

or another way is just remove `android:onClick="setOnClickListener"` from layout button and implement **onClickListener** as

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
           //do your job
       }
   });
```

Comment: I did, everything is in onCreate(), I delete the onclick part in xml file but it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `android:onClick` attribute from Button from your xml layout

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/calculate" />
```

**Updated**

I found the issue what you doing

```
// Loan Term processing
int[] termGroup = {180, 240, 360};
int selectedTerm = loanTerm.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
int selectedTermIndex = 0;
noOfLoanMonth = termGroup[selectedTerm];
```

Here is 3 line you getting error at last line. In termGroup[] is starting from 0 index to 1,2 now `loanTerm.getCheckedRadioButtonId();` will giving you RadioButton reference ID and it may be something like 392032489 etc which is generated in R.java file. You need to get which position of RadioButton is selected like this way.

```
switch(selectedTerm){
case R.id.radiobtn1:
    selectedTermIndex = 0;
    break;
case R.id.radiobtn2:
    selectedTermIndex = 1;
    break;
case R.id.radiobtn3:
    selectedTermIndex = 2;
    break;
}
```

Now use `selectedTermIndex` instead of `selectedTerm`

```
noOfLoanMonth = termGroup[selectedTermIndex];
```

Hope this will be work for you

Comment: go to the logcat tab from ddms and check the error you getting for your app